# Postgresql how to convert insert value as parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a insert sql:

```
cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_patient (patient_id, patient_name) VALUES
                      (1,'Jane'),(2,'John')""")
```

I tired use parameters in query and pass the values separately:

```
cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_patient (patient_id, patient_name) VALUES
                      (%s,%s),(%s,%s)""",(1,'Jane'),(2,'John'))
```

Error:

```
cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_patient (patient_id, patient_name) VALUES
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

any friend can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `executemany()` here:

```py
sql = 'INSERT INTO patients_patient (patient_id, patient_name) VALUES (?, ?)'
values = [(1, 'Jane'), (2, 'John')]
cur.executemany(sql, values)
```

If you don't know a priori how many tuples to expect in the `VALUES` clause, then you may build it dynamically:

```py
sql = 'INSERT INTO patients_patient (patient_id, patient_name) VALUES '
values = [(1, 'Jane'), (2, 'John')]
sql += '(%s' + ',%s'*(len(values)-1) + ')'
cur.executemany(sql, values)
```

Comment: Hi Tim,thanks,I have another one:  cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_event_type (type_name) VALUES
                     ('HR'),('RR')""") it not works,can you help me?

Comment: Well for starters why are you using `execute()` instead of `executeMany()` ?

Comment: The sql I post here works,but I copyed your last code ,it not work for this one.I want to change this one is because I want to use  parameters.

Comment: Hi friend also help with this related one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69952301/postgresql-insert-if-not-exists-on-conflict-ignore-not-working