# Postgresql insert if not exists ON CONFLICT IGNORE not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a postgres sql:

```
        cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_patient (patient_id, patient_name) VALUES
                  (1,'Jane'),(2,'John')""")
```

My question is how to make it not insert if data already exists ?

I tried ON CONFLICT IGNORE:

```
        cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_patient (patient_id, patient_name) VALUES
                  (1,'Jane'),(2,'John') ON CONFLICT IGNORE""")
```

But not working.

Any friend can help?

Comment: It sould be [ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). Do you have unique constraints by the way?

Answer (score -1):

You can insert data using a manual check with the query:

```
WITH ins AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,'Jane'),(2,'John')) AS t(patient_id, patient_name)
)
insert into patients_patient  (patient_id, patient_name)
select t1.patient_id, t1.patient_name from ins t1
left join patients_patient t2 on t2.patient_id = t1.patient_id 
where t2.patient_id is null;
```